# Imports are incorrectly sorted and/or formatted | VS Code | Python

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, python-import, syntax-highlighting

In a few of my beginner projects this strange red line underscoring one or more of my imports keeps appearing almost randomly and I can't figure out why.
As the module is working perfectly fine it shouldn't have something to do regarding which Folder I open VS Code in as it can get resolved, so `sys.path` should also have the right path, as far as I'm concerned.
Sometimes it works when I switch my imports around but often it just underscores a single import or switching them around doesn't do anything.
Also when I try to let VS Code sort them with isort, nothing happens and nothing had ever happened.

Comment: You need to provide sample code

Comment: My guess is your linter is complaining about unused imports.  Hover over the red underscored word and see what the message is.

Comment: you can disable auto imports from `settings > pylance > auto import completions` it's being annoying sometimes

Comment: I suspect this is a bug with VS Code v1.72. Today, several files that I had open started displaying incorrectly-sorted import errors, even those I haven't touched for weeks. I re-installed v1.71, and the errors have disappeared. I can't be sure when my VS Code application updated itself, so my hypothesis might not be correct, but downgrading certainly fixed it.

Comment: I think this error is caused by the recently added isort extension. See my answer below.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Edit: I realized that recently the [isort extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-python.isort) from Microsoft was automatically added to my extensions and this has caused the annoying error to start showing. It may be that the extension is conflicting somehow with the `isort` library installed in your venv. The extension isn't needed, so I've just disabled it and no longer encounter this error.

It seems like this error started happening after I recently updated my VS Code to 1.73.0 (Insiders). I was able to get around it by splitting up my imports so that they don't get auto-formatted to be on multiple lines.

Here's an example:

Before the "fix", notice the squiggly red line with the annoying error:
[image]

After the "fix", no more squiggly red line:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I have had the same issue.

seems to be related to what's been discussed [here](https://lightrun.com/answers/microsoft-vscode-python-disable-import-sorting-for-virtualenv)
I got around warnings by telling the formatter to ignore the error--  i.e. put this in your vscode config :

```js
"python.formatting.autopep8Args": ["--ignore=E402"],
```

Answer (score 0):

As I didn't want to disable the auto imports like @Ahmet Burak suggested, I tried to uninstall VS Code after hours of searching for solutions, reinstalled it, copied over my settings and it still wasn't working.
Then I got more and more desperate, so I uninstalled it again on the next day, installed it, copied over my settings and somehow sorting imports with isort is working just fine now even though I have the same settings and setup as before.
I can't explain what the issue really was but at least it is working.

Edit: After thinking about it, the problem was most likely exactly what @Wesley described in his answer as the problem went away after I had started working on a new project in a new venv. Therefore, my reinstalls where completely pointless and not at all fixing the issue!

Comment: try the following steps:
1. mouse over the red line "Imports are incorrectly sorted and/or formatted"
2. click QuickFix
3. click isort

Comment: @FreeToGo, thank you so much.  That fixed my issue.  However, the fix returns exactly what I have in the first place.  Could you elaborate on what is happening?

Comment: @FreeToGo Please read the entire question and my answer to it. I tried sorting the imports with isort but as it didn't work anymore I started sorting them manually which didn't help until I reinstalled VS Code a few times over the span of 2 days.

Answer (score 0):

I disabled the **Microsoft** isort (2022.2.0) extension and the problem went away. Watch out, there is another isort out there.